# discriminant and irreducibility of $x^p - (p+1)x - 1$

Tags: galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, discriminant

I proved that if the discriminant of a monic polynomial with $p > 5$ an odd prime is nonzero it has at least 3 roots in the reals. I'm trying to apply that result to this polynomial  $f(x) = x^p - (p+1)x - 1$, how can I show that it has a nonzero discriminant?

Also, how do I show that $f(x)$ mod $p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$? My approach was to suppose that $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_p$ is a root, then 
$f(\alpha) = \alpha^p - (p+1)\alpha - 1$. But the field has characteristic $p$, so $\alpha^p = \alpha$ and $p\alpha = 0$, which means $f(\alpha) = -1$, and $\alpha$ can't be a root. How can I proceed from here?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81583/11619) please find several nice proofs for the irreducibility of this polynomial in $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$.

Comment: Can you use [the formula for the discriminant of trinomials of this form](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/440452/11619)? (I swear to the deity of your choice that I didn't remember having answered that latter question as well. I just knew that we had handled it here. May be I'm getting better with the search engine?)

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the second question:

If $$g(X)h(X)\equiv X^p-X-1\pmod{p}$$
then
$$g'(X)h(X)+g(X)h'(X)\equiv -1\pmod p$$